# How to push data to firebase storage from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was wondering how to get `UITextField` strings to push to the firebase storage. I am creating a signup page for an app and can't get it to work 100%. Its pushing data to realtime database but not to storage.

```
@IBAction func SignUpButton2(_ sender: Any) {
      Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: EmailAuthProviderID, password: EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod) { (user, error) in
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document("Profiles").setData([
            "email": self.emailTextField,
            "name": self.usernameTextField,
            "password": self.passwordTextField
        ]) { err in
           if let err = err {
               print("Error writing document: \(err)")
           } else {
               print("Document successfully written!")
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `EmailAuthProviderID` & `EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod` why you are not passing the `self.emailTextField` & `self.passwordTextField` instead of this?

Comment: That's bad, you are sending user sensitive data with no encryption to a database table that is not for this kind of stuff. Why would you do that?

Comment: I’m super new to all this and I’m open to suggestions !!!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your doing this for a tutorial or learning purposes but it's very bad to send the password like this on plain text without encrypting it

however you should pass `self.emailTextField.text` not `self.emailTextField` or 
`EmailAuthProviderID` & `EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod`